How to Execute Robotic Arm Control Code on Raspberry Pi 4 Using C++ or Python?
I’m working on a robotic arm project for my thesis, and I need guidance on how to execute the control code on a Raspberry Pi 4. Here’s the system overview:

Robotic Arm Components:

Desktop application (Code Editor): Students write C++ or Python code for motor control, kinematics, etc.
Raspberry Pi 4: Acts as the brain of the system, reads sensors, and executes calculations.
Arduino Mega: Controls the motors and servos of the robotic arm.


Workflow

Students write code in either C++ or Python using the desktop application (Customized Code Editor).
They save the code to a USB drive.
The USB drive is plugged into the Raspberry Pi 4.
The Raspberry Pi reads the code files and executes them with help of ROS.
Motor control commands are sent to the Arduino Mega.


Communication Workflow

Desktop Application → USB Drive → Raspberry Pi 4 (ROS) reads/executes the program → Arduino Mega (Motor Control)


Questions

How do I compile and run C++ programs on the Raspberry Pi 4?
What’s the process for executing Python scripts on the Raspberry Pi?
Should I integrate ROS into my Python scripts for better communication with the robotic arm components?



Any advice, code examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.
You can check this link that shows how my project works more clearly.

You need to step through the official ros docs. The questions you're asking are all very basic and can all be answered by reading the first few pages of the docs.
